# Constant error: Plugin [id: 'com.android.library'] was not found in any of the following sources:

Tags: android, compiler-errors

I keep getting the error. My plugin is installed, but i keep getting the same error in my code:

```
 buildscript {
     repositories {
         google()
         mavenCentral()
     }
     dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1'
         classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.30" // Update the Kotlin      version if needed
     }
 }

 plugins {
     id 'com.android.library'
     id 'kotlin-android'
     id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.0-Beta' apply false
 }

 android {
     compileSdkVersion 33

     defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 21
         targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
     }

     buildTypes {
         release {
             minifyEnabled false
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-     rules.pro'
         }
     }
 }

 dependencies {
     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
     implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
     implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
 }
```

I tried synching, restarting AndroidStudio, updating the version, etc but nothing seems to work.